# How to format date in Android in dd/mm/yy 00:00AM

Tags: android, date, date-format, android-calendar

How to format my date in Android. I have String which gets date in below format

```
String format = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Output

```
25 Nov 2013 17:39:00
```

I want this to be converted in below format

```
dd/mm/yy 5:39PM
```

I am using below code to get Date. Also how to get that format into String ?

Comment: Before asking some basic question , please find it over here and in case  you'll not get the solution ... Update the question over here ...

Answer (score 7):

Using `SimpleDateFormat` class you can do it.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");
String format = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: Yes, I know i can do like this 
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");

but then how do u convert it into string ?

Comment: @user45678 notice that am using the lowercase 'hh' in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor. And the next statement will give you parsed string

Comment: @D3m0li5h3r - Doing that way giving me output "java.text.SimpleDateFormat@66345ded"

Answer (score 0):

please try follwing answer

```
      SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
     java.util.Date date = null;
     try 
    {
    date = form.parse("2011-03-27T09:39:01.607");
   }
  catch (ParseException e) 
  {

   e.printStackTrace();
   }
   SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
   String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks but output was completely irrelevant "March 27" !!! This is November 25'2013

Comment: change like this SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm");

Comment: Which line ? There are two "SimpleDateFormat" lines

Answer (score -1):

I got it, This has to go like this

```
 Date today = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);

                DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy  hh:mm:ss aa");
                date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
```