# Get the date from the edittext

Tags: android, date, datepicker, android-edittext

How can i get the value of date which i set in edittext

```
 mDateSelect.setText(getString(R.string.strSelectedDate,
            new StringBuilder()

            .append(mDay).append("/")
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
            .append(mYear).append(" "))
            );
```

This is my code for setting the date in the edittext from the datepicker(mDateSelect is the edittext).I am setting my date from the datepicker into the edittext.Now i have to get the date which has been set in dd/mm/yyyy format.Below is my code.

```
String dob_var=(mDateSelect.getText().toString());
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        dateObject = formatter.parse(dob_var);
        Log.e("date is ", dateObject+"");
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is giving me the time as Wed Aug 03 00:00:00 EDT 2011

Comment: Does mDateSelect.getText() work?what is the problem here?

Comment: please look at the editted question for the error

Comment: Does this question help you in anyways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193791/how-to-format-date-in-android-in-dd-mm-yy-0000am

Comment: no insomniac i just needed to use String dob_var=(mDateSelect.getText().toString()); to get my desired result                 Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Setting the date value to your EditText properly and now you want to get the EditText value which you set means use this code this will work out.

```
String datevalue = mDateSelect.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton...only the above code gives me the date in dd/mm/yyyy.There was no need for DateFormatter and stuffs like that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get date object for your editText then you can do something like this :

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static String formatDate(String inputDate) {
        String formattedDate;
        try {
            DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); //Input date format

            DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); //Output date format
            Date date = originalFormat.parse(inputDate);
            formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
            return formattedDate;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "no_date";
    }
```

Comment: I got the answer.Need only use                                             String dob_var=(mDateSelect.getText().toString());                       to get the date in dd/mm/yyyy